# How to improve performance of LDA (latent dirichlet allocation) in sci-kit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, lda, topic-modeling

I am running LDA on health-related data. Specifically I have ~500 documents that contain interviews that last around 5-7 pages. While I cannot really go into the details of the data or results due to preserving data integrity/confidentiality, I will describe the results and go through the procedure to give a better idea of what I am doing and where I can improve.

For the results, I chose 20 topics and outputted 10 words per topic. Although 20 was somewhat arbitrary and I did not have a clear idea of a good amount of topics, that seemed like a good amount given the size of the data and that they are all health-specific. However, the results highlighted two issues: 1) it is unclear what the topics were since the words within each topic did not necessarily go together or tell a story and 2) many of the words among the various topics overlapped, and there were a few words that showed up in most topics.

In terms of what I did, I first preprocessed the text. I converted everything to lowercase, removed punctuation, removed unnecessary codings specific to the set of documents at hand. I then tokenized the documents, lemmatized the words, and performed tf-idf. I used sklearn's tf-idf capabilities and within tf-idf initialization, I specified a customized list of stopwords to be removed (which added to nltk's set of stopwords). I also set max_df to 0.9 (unclear what a good number is, I just played around with different values), min_df to 2, and max_features to 5000. I tried both tf-idf and bag of words (count vectorizer), but I found tf-idf to give slightly clearer and more distinct topics while analyzing the LDA output. After this was done, I then ran an LDA model. I set the number of topics to be 20 and the number of iterations to 5.

From my understanding, each decision I made above may have contributed to the LDA model's ability to identify clear, meaningful topics. I know that text processing plays a huge role in LDA performance, and the better job I do there, the more insightful the LDA will be.

- Is there anything glaringly wrong or something I missed out. Do you have any suggested values/explorations for any of the parameters I described above?
- How detailed, nit-picky should I be when filtering out potential domain-specific stopwords?
- How do I determine a good number of topics and iterations during the LDA step?
- How can I go about validating performance, other than qualitatively comparing output?

I appreciate all insights and input. I am completely new to the area of topic modeling and while I have read some articles, I have a lot to learn! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> How do I determine a good number of topics and iterations during the LDA step?

This is the most difficult question in clustering algorithms like LDA. There is a metric that can determine which number of cluster is the best https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/topic_coherence_tutorial.ipynb

In my experience optimizing this metric by tuning number of topics, iterations or another hyper-parameters won't necessarily give you interpretable topics.

> How can I go about validating performance, other than qualitatively comparing output?

Again you may use the above metric to validate the performance, but I also found useful visualization of the topics http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bmabey/pyLDAvis/blob/master/notebooks/pyLDAvis_overview.ipynb

This not only gives you topic histograms but also shows how apart are the topics, which again may help with finding out optimal number of topics.

In my studies I was not using scikit, but rather [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/topic_modeling_tutorial/2%20-%20Topic%20Modeling.html).